After Logging In Successfully The Back Button Still Takes Me Back To The Login Page
After logging in successfully, the back button still takes me back to the login page. I am able to login successfully and view user only pages but whenever I click on the back button, I am able to get back to the Login Page even without logging out.
Here is my Main.dart:
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

  Future<bool> userIsLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool? _isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
    return _isLoggedIn ?? false;
  }

  //This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: userIsLoggedIn(),
        builder: (context, dataSnapShot)
        {
          if(dataSnapShot.data == true){
            return HomePage();
          }else{
            return LoginPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    ); //MaterialApp
  }
}

Here is the Login function. What could be wrong while the page is still able to return to the login page when a user click on the back button. Is there a way to further force the user out of the Login or registration pages if the user is already logged in.
loginUser() async{
      try{
        final uri = Uri.parse(API.loginURL);
        var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

        //Send Input field data
        request.fields['email'] = emailController.text;
        request.fields['password'] = passwordController.text;

        var response = await request.send();

        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          var responseData = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
          var resBody = jsonDecode(responseData.body);
          bool successFlag = resBody['success'];
          String message = resBody['message'];

          if (successFlag) {

              //Get user data from server
              User currentUser = User.fromJson(resBody['userData']);

              //Save user data to local storage
              await UserPerfs.saveUserPerfs(currentUser);
              
              //Save user sessionData to local storage
              String sessionData = resBody['sessionData'];
              final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              await prefs.setString('sessionData', sessionData);
              //Set isLoggedIn to true
              await prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);

              //Route user to the home page
              Get.to(() => HomePage());

          } else {
              //Show error message
              setState(() {
                errorMsg = message;
                flagError = true;
              });
          }

        }else{
            //Connection to server failed! Check your internet connection
            setState(() {
              errorMsg = 'Connection to server failed! Check your internet connection';
              flagError = true;
            });
        }
      }
      catch(e){
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }


share login page code.

I have added the Login Code

change
Get.to(() => HomePage());

to
Get.off(() => HomePage());

Explanation:
Why it happens:
By default, Get.to(() => HomePage()) pushes the HomePage onto the navigation stack. When you press the back button, it simply pops the topmost page (HomePage) from the stack, potentially revealing the LoginPage underneath.
Here is approach to address this issue:
Replace the Login Page with the Home Page:
Instead of pushing the HomePage, you can replace the LoginPage with it. This ensures the LoginPage is removed from the navigation history. Use Get.off(() => HomePage()) for this.
see more about navigation using get here at offical get doc
